# buttonStyle ignores colorButtonNormal

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-theme

I am trying to change the background tint of the default Android Button.
The `app:backgroundTint` attribute has bugs, so I don't use it (Pre-Lollipop devices lose their state list)

`colorButtonNormal` added to the app theme works, but if I instead add it to a child theme and use the `buttonStyle` attribute on the app theme, `colorButtonNormal` for some reason gets ignored (all the other child theme attributes are applied).

Is this a bug?

This is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/BlueButton</item>
</style>

<style name="BlueButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>  <-- not applied
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY SOMETHING LIKE BELOW IN YOUR styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="android:textColor">#yourcolor</item>
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonColor</item>
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/buttonColor</item>
</style>



 <style name="ButtonColor" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
 <item name="android:textColor">@color/yourcolor</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: This is a clever and working solution, thank you. I am hoping that I can still find some sort of clarification why this attribute is not working in the style. Do you have any idea?